# Is this good approach to use debug functions for implementing features?

Tags: php, functional-programming

Just thinking if using code like this

```
<?php

abstract class helper
{
    private static $_cycles = array();

    public static function isOdd($v)
    {
        return (0 == ($v % 2)) ? false: true;
    }

    public static function isEven($v)
    {
        return !self::isOdd($v);
    }

    public static function cycle($odd, $even)
    {
        $trace = debug_backtrace();
        $trace = $trace[0];
        $cycle = crc32(serialize($trace));

        if (!isset(self::$_cycles[$cycle]))
        {
            self::$_cycles[$cycle] = 1;
        }

        return (self::isOdd(self::$_cycles[$cycle]++)) ? $odd : $even;
    }
}
```

for featues like this

```
<?php foreach ($data as $record): ?>
    <p class="<?php echo helper::cycle('oddCss', 'evenCss'); ?>"><?php echo $record; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

is not overcoded

PS
Easy of usage (by html/css coders) is more important then performance in this particular case

UPDATE:
As @Geoffrey mentioned i didn't tell before that same 'oddCss', 'evenCss' pair may be used several times on one page (so basically within one request)

Comment: I'm guessing that the second code block is what the HTML/CSS people will need to write?

Comment: @Michael that's right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, using debug_backtrace for it (clearly not the fastest function in the town) is a huge overkill. What about passing id? Advantage, besides of performance, is that you can use the same counter in different places.

Code:

```
<?php

abstract class helper
{

    protected static $_cycles = array();

    public static function cycle($cycle_id, $odd, $even)
    {

        self::$_cycles[$cycle_id] = isset(self::$_cycles[$cycle_id]) ? !self::$_cycles[$cycle_id] : true;

        return self::$_cycles[$cycle_id] ? $odd : $even;
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
<?php foreach ($data as $record): ?>
    <p class="<?php echo helper::cycle('mycycle', 'oddCss', 'evenCss'); ?>"><?php echo $record; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
// Data from another source, but continuous display
<?php foreach ($data2 as $record): ?>
    <p class="<?php echo helper::cycle('mycycle', 'oddCss', 'evenCss'); ?>"><?php echo $record; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: This solution is perfect and its quite similar to my first attempt which was passing array idx (`foreach ($data as $k => $v)`) and checking only odd/even. Passing simple $cycle_id is real compromise between backend and frontend programmers. Thanks for fresh look and great idea about this question!

Answer (score 5):

Since this is a code review site, let me point out that the following is an abomination:

```
return (0 == ($v % 2)) ? false: true;
```

The constants are redundant. Much simpler:

```
return (0 != ($v % 2));
```

(The parentheses are also redundant but that’s unrelated.)

Comment: I like the parentheses, though. I think it clarifies the statement quite a bit.

Comment: The original returned true for even, false for odd. The above reverses those. Try `return (bool) ($v % 2)` or if you don't like the case, `return ($v % 2 == 1)`.

Comment: @David Good call. I should have paid better attention.

Answer (score 3):

Something a bit simpler (without logging):

```
class Cycler {
   $evenFlag = true;

   /* Returns the next value in an even/odd series */
   function next($odd, $even) {
      $evenFlag = !evenFlag;

      return $evenFlag? $even: $odd;
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
<?php Cycler cycler = new Cycler(); ?>
<?php foreach ($data as $record): ?> 
   <p class="<?php echo cycler.next('oddCss', 'evenCss'); ?>"><?php echo $record; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You could also add a `reset()` if you wanted to use the `Cycler` multiple times.

Comment: Just remember that when sth is simple for programmers (e.g. .next() .reset() methods) its not always easy for html/css coders

Comment: That is perhaps true for reset. I don't think next is too much of a challenge. However it isn't the most descriptive - maybe flip or switch? ideas...

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly over-engineered. The `isOdd` and `isEven` method are useless since they're just the result of `fmod($i, 2)`

I'm guessing you're using the crc part to keep track of specific cycles for $odd/$even, couples, but this is not needed. Instead, you can just hash the arguments and keep a counter for that hash.

Last, I think static are an heresy, and I'd much like an instanciated helper.

I would have written something like that, assuming `$odd` and `$even` are always strings (not tested):

```
<?php

class helper
{
  private $cycles = array();

  function cycle($odd, $even)
  {
    $hash = md5($odd.$even);

    if (!isset($this->cycles[$hash]))
    {
      $this->cycles[$hash] = 0;
    }

    return fmod($this->cycles[$hash]++, 2) ? $odd : $even;
  }
}

$helper = new helper();

$helper->cycle('foo', 'bar');
```

Comment: your solution fails when i need 2 or more cycles with the same $odd $even values on the same page

Comment: oh I see. you should have told that in your question :-) Anyway, with that in mind, I don't see another solution right now (but my other remarks still apply :p)

Comment: Yea, my bad. Thanks for pointing that out (updated) and thanks for the tips also

Answer (score 0):

I think CodeIgniter has something like this (yup, the [`alternator()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/string_helper.html) helper):

```
function Cycle()
{
    static $i = 0;

    if (func_num_args() > 0)
    {
        return func_get_arg($i++ % func_num_args());
    }

    return $i = 0;
}
```

Works for a variable number of arguments, which might be useful in certain scenarios.